# How to extract content between <text></text> tags in Perl from huge xml file of Wikipedia (it can be any XML)?

Tags: xml, perl

How to extract content between `<text></text>` tags in perl from Wikipedia?

I want to process `utf-8` **huge file** - loading into memory not possible. File contains `<text>.*?</text>` for each page - this is possible to be loaded into memory - and it should be load into some variable to do some further processing:

```
      <text xml:space="preserve">Some text without &lt; or &lt; ....
... more text ...
... more text ...</text>
```

Consider that text not starts line and not ends line - important content is between `<text></text>`. I want to extract it and improve to generate some text file for nlp machine learning.

File can be download with:

```
wget http://dumps.wikimedia.org/plwiki/latest/plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

File can be turn into stdin pipe with:

```
bzip2 -c -d plwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 | perl something > data.txt
```

I am not very good in Perl and can not write good code. Not know how to learn matched position, to do micro state machine or to do moving window.

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Should be pretty simple with [XML::Twig reading chunks of data](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#Processing-an-XML-document-chunk-by-chunk).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

sub text_handler {
    my ( $twig, $text_elt ) = @_; 
    print $text_elt -> text; 
    $twig -> purge; 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'text' => \&text_handler } ) ->  parsefile ( 'your_xml');
```

Note the trick here is that `purge` which discards previously processed XML. You can probably set a purge on other elements too, if there's a lot of stuff inbetween 'text' nodes.